Well pump is always running
My well pump is always running and my electricity bill is insane. What can I do to have it run less? Should I get a bigger water pressurized tank?


"Always running" as in it never stops even for a second? Or just runs more often than you think it should?

Fix a broken pressure switch maybe?

First investigate if you have a leak somewhere and patch it.
With the rest of the house isolated check that the pressure switch shuts off the pump when the desired pressure is reached. If it never shuts of the pressure switch has failed and needs replacement.
If it can never reach the desired pressure then it's an issue with the pump or the line from the well.
When the pressure is reached then see whether it can maintain that pressure when nothing is drawing water and the pump is off. Shut off the valve to the rest of the house if necessary. If it cannot the checkvalve is failing failing.
